# Jquery AutoSuggestion from Excel File

Tags: php, jquery, excel, autosuggest

I was just wondering if anybody knows how to make one of those autosuggestion textboxes so that when you begin typing, it will autosuggest based off of an excel file? I've searched everywhere and couldn't find anything, and I don't know where to begin.

Creating the autosuggestion is not my issue, it's just getting the data from the excel file and displaying it to suggest something relevant to what they're typing.

I'd appreciate any help at all. Thank you

Comment: This will hardly work with an excel file. Is exporting the file to CSV an option, and uploading that?

Comment: I would be more than happy to export to CSV if that's what it takes to get the job done. :)

Answer (score 0):

From a high level perspective, you'll need to use ajax to grab a file and parse its contents. Once you've done that, you can begin checking the user input for matches to the parsed content.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it to stay as Excel?

You could export it to xml if you like.. that'd make things a lot easier.
If you're bent on using some tabular formatted data, might I suggest mysql, or even sqlite?

PS: A cursory google search reveals:
1. http://amiworks.co.in/talk/readingparsing-excel-spreadsheet-using-php/
2. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-phpexcel/index.html

Comment: I can save the excel file as XML. But then, I'd still have absolutely no idea

Comment: I have just given up on trying to export an Excel file AND a CSV file into my MySQL database, after reading over and over the documentation on how to do it, I get a wiiiiiiiiiiiide range of errors, the most perculiar of errors is "Access denied, incorrect password: "YES"", and my password is not YES, and access denied my ass, it'll let me perform other queries, just not load infile ones

Comment: Well in that case, do what a real programmer would do: write a perl script to import your data into sql (maybe have excel do the csv export first).